# What is the bivariate mark variogram (MVF) analyzer for numeric markers in spatstat?

Tags: r, spatstat

My goal is to use bivariate marks variogram to analyze correlations between trees with different radial levels. But I didn't find a bivariate function about numeric markers, tried the markcorr function (where the f parameter is set to `f = function(m1, m2) { (m1 - m2)^2 / 2}`)and the markvario function, I can't manipulate bivariate mode. How should I apply the markcorr or markvario function between trees of different diameters (e.g. DBH<5 for young trees and DBH>10 for large trees)?

I used the markcorr and markvario functions for univariate pattern analysis, as well as multi-type analysis (labeled at the factor level),  but did not master the bivariate analysis code for numeric markers (breast diameter), and I also tried setting the f parameter in the markcorr function.

**univariate patterns：**

```
X1 <- ppp(X[,2],X[,3],c(0,100),c(0,100),marks = X$DBH)   #DBH is the tree diameter
plot(envelope(X1,markvario,normalise = T,nsim = 199,    simulate=expression(rlabel(X1,labels=marks(X1),permute=TRUE)), savefuns=TRUE,savepatterns=TRUE) )
Y2 <- ppp(Y[,2],Y[,3],c(0,100),c(0,100),marks = Y$DBH)
plot(envelope(Y2,markvario,normalise = T,nsim = 199,    simulate=expression(rlabel(Y2,labels=marks(Y2),permute=TRUE)), savefuns=TRUE,savepatterns=TRUE) )
```

**bivariate patterns:**
What would be the strategy for bivariate comparison between the X1 and Y2 pattern points, using a mark variogram function`markvario`?

Answer (score 0):

The mark correlation function and mark variogram are designed for numeric marks (such as tree diameter). If you want to apply them to binary marks, you could "trick" these functions by simply converting the data to binary values, e.g.

```
X <- longleaf
marks(X) <- as.integer(marks(X) > 5)
```

and then applying `markcorr` or `markvario`.

However, it would be more advisable to use the functions that are specifically designed for multitype point patterns (point patterns where the points are classified into different types). The functions include `markconnect` and `pcfcross`.

Example:

```
X <- cut(longleaf, breaks=c(0, 5, 10, Inf))
plot(markconnect(X))
plot(alltypes(X, markconnect))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!  I cut the markers using cut.ppp based on your suggestion, but the returned markers are of the factor type and do not perform bivariate marks variogram analysis. My ultimate goal is to use the bivariate markvario function (e.g. calculating the correlation of two patterns of numeric markers, which are the marker for adult breast diameter and the marker for juvenile breast diameter), is there any good solution?

Comment: You didn't do what I said. If you convert the marks to categorical (factor) values then the available functions include `markconnect` and `pcfcross`. If you convert them to integers taking the values 0 and 1, you can use `markvario` as explained at the top of my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't make it clear, I wanted to ask about bivariate marks instead of binary. I put the code for univariate marks variogram on it, how do I implement bivariate analysis?